# Send an e-mail using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtplib

I'm working on a guessing game where there are tons of characters and it gives you hints for you to guess the character. There is also going to be a thing where you can submit a character. I want to do it so that it will send me an e-mail if somebody submits a character, but it's not working. Here's my code:

```
import smtplib

FROM = 'Guess@Character.com'
TO = ["mikpe120@gmail.com"] # must be a list
SUBJECT = "Somebody submitted a character!"
TEXT = "Name: "  + name + "NameType: " + nameType

# Prepare actual message
message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

# Send the mail
server = smtplib.SMTP('myserver')
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()
```

And here is the error that I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mikolaj Perzyna/Desktop/addCharacter.py", line 106, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP('myserver')
  File "C:\Users\Mikolaj Perzyna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\Mikolaj Perzyna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\smtplib.py", line 335, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Mikolaj Perzyna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\smtplib.py", line 306, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\Mikolaj Perzyna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 704, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\Mikolaj Perzyna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 743, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

I'm sorry if I'm formatting this post wrong, which I probably am, but this is my first question on the site.

Answer (score 0):

`getaddrinfo failed` means that the socket connection `smptlib.SMTP` uses failed to resolve the hostname of the server. Try a different SMTP server or a different IP/hostname.

Answer (score 0):

This line is almost certainly wrong.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('myserver')
```

Is your SMTP server *really* called `myserver`? I'd expect to see something like `mail.mydomain.com` there.